# trying to update item in firebase from app but it just adds another item

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update item in my app but when i send it off to be updates it just adds another item. I am new to android so dont know why it is happening. I am storing the car items in a recyclerview. this is the recycler view I am using:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, eventAdapter>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull eventAdapter holder, int position, @NonNull final Event model) {
        holder.make.setText(model.getCarMake());
        holder.type.setText(model.getCarType());
        holder.year.setText(model.getCarYear());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), updateDeleteCars.class);
                intent.putExtra("make", model.getCarMake());
                intent.putExtra("type", model.getCarType());
                intent.putExtra("year", model.getCarYear());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Each item can be clicked and it then bring you to the update page. this is that page

```
public class updateDeleteCars extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button update;
    Button delete;
    EditText make;
    EditText type;
    EditText year;
    TextView cancel;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String userId;
    private String key;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_delete_cars);

        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateCar);
        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteCar);
        cancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cancelCar);
        make = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateMake);
        type = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateType);
        year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateYear);

        make.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("make"));
        type.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
        year.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("year"));
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userId = user.getUid();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cars").child(userId);
        key = databaseReference.getKey();

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.child(key).child("carMake").setValue(make.getText().toString());
                databaseReference.child(key).child("carType").setValue(type.getText().toString());
                databaseReference.child(key).child("carYear").setValue(year.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.child(key).removeValue();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think its because there is know actual link between the item i click and the item i am uploading. My database structure has nested keys so I think my problem is I'm not accessing the nested key. this is m database structure:

[image: database Structure]

The second item happened when I tried to update the first item.
Any suggestions?

Edit:
Stacktrace

```
Process: com.example.carcrashdetection, PID: 9023
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.carcrashdetection.Event
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:435)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:203)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:109)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:149)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
2020-04-28 00:24:39.908 9023-9023/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6858)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:743)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24710)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2041)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2336)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1929)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7987)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1154)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:977)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1139)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you click an item in the `recyclerview` pass the pressed key:**

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), updateDeleteCars.class);
            intent.putExtra("make", model.getCarMake());
            intent.putExtra("type", model.getCarType());
            intent.putExtra("year", model.getCarYear());
            //here
            intent.putExtra("key", key);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Now you get this passed key in your update activity, and do the update:**

```
public class updateDeleteCars extends AppCompatActivity {

.........
.........

//don't use the key that you made

//use this
private String passedKey;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_delete_cars);


     ........
     //this is what we will use
     passedKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

    ............

     }
```

Update like this:

```
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            databaseReference.child(passedKey).child("carMake").setValue(make.getText().toString());
            databaseReference.child(passedKey).child("carType").setValue(type.getText().toString());
            databaseReference.child(passedKey).child("carYear").setValue(year.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get this error for some reason                                                                      `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.carcrashdetection.Event`

Comment: I added my stack trace as I cant see where its coming from.

Comment: Does this error come when you open the `updateDeleteCars ` activity?

Comment: sorry I fixed it it was something i tried to do earlier that made it crash. This works thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cars").child(userId);
key = databaseReference.getKey();
```

Is a very convoluted way of saying:

```
key = userId;
```

So when you then do `databaseReference.child(key)....setValue(...)` you're creating a new child with the `userId` under the existing `userId`.

---

If you want to update an existing car under the user ID node, you'll to already know the child node's key:

```
databaseReference.child("-M5vP3HXN5UINkvZFJ0q").child("carMake").setValue(make.getText().toString())
```

---

If you don't know the key, you'll first need to read the data to determine the child key(s):

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot carSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            carSnapshot.getRef()..child("carMake").setValue(make.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The `for` loop is needed here because you may have multiple child nodes under the user ID node. If you don't want to have multiple child nodes, don't call `push()` when you're adding the car data.

---

If you know a unique property value of the child node to update, you can use a query to select just those nodes:

```
databaseReference
  .orderByChild("carMake")
  .equalTo("renouot")
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

Keep in mind that this may still match multiple child nodes, so the `for` loop is needed as before.

---

A final note: you're now calling `setValue()` three times to set the data for the car. While this may give you the right result, it'll likely create problems down the line. It's best to perform a single write operation for the entire update, which you can do with:

```
HashMap<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("carMake", make.getText().toString());
values.put("carType", type.getText().toString());
values.put("carYear", year.getText().toString());
databaseReference.setValue(values);
```

Comment: Hi frank I've tried your method and it updates but for some reason it updates all them items to be the same.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the second approach with the `for` loop. That one will indeed update all child nodes, as I have no way to know which one you'd want to update. If you **do** know something unique about which child to update, you can use a query to select just that child.

Comment: ah okay so I have to try access the key underneath the userID

Comment: That is what my first solution shows. Notice the `-M...` in there, which is the key of the child node/

Comment: yeah but the thing is Id have to hard code that ID wouldn't I?

Comment: I show all these cases in my answer: 1) you know the key, 2) you don't know the key, but want to process all child nodes, 3) you don't know the key, but know something that allows you to look it up.